# Mocha and Chai GET request test doesn't work

Tags: node.js, express, mocha.js, httprequest, chai

I'm trying to test the GET request on the home root '/'. The route doesn't exist in my file root.js because 
I want that the test fails but it always succeeds. 
I don't understand why. There are 3 files: ./test/test.js, ./server/server.js and ./server/routes/index.js

```js
/*File: ./test/test.js */
/* eslint-env mocha */
const chai = require('chai')
const chaiHttp = require('chai-http')

const { expect } = chai
const app = require('../server/server.js')

chai.use(chaiHttp)

describe('GET Home', () => {
  it('Should return Not found', () => {
    chai
      .request(app)
      .get('/', (err, res) => {
        const result = res.statusCode
        expect(result).to.equal(200)
      })
  })
})

/*File: ./server/server.js */
const express = require('express')
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')
const config = require('./config.js')
const mainRoutes = require('./routes')

const app = express()

app.set('view engine', 'jade')

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }))
app.use(mainRoutes)

app.listen(config.port, () => {
  console.log(`The application is running on localhost:${config.port}`)
})

module.exports = app

/*File: ./server/routes/index.js*/
const express = require('express')

const router = express.Router()

// router.get('/', (req, res) => {
//   res.render('home')
// })

module.exports = router
```

Comment: Can you post your server.js or where you have your routes defined?

Comment: Yes, I updated my post

Comment: routes/index.js might be interesting as well. I think you might have two problems:
1) You have a route set in routes/index.js that we haven't seen yet
2) You're using jade, maybe it sets a default page
I'd suggest running you server locally and see the result of a GET request to the route. You can do this from your browser, or with Postman.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because `get` run async, you need to call `done()` for assertion `expect(result).to.equal(200)` to get checked, otherwise your test will always passed no matter your router exists or not. Checkout this [page](http://chaijs.com/plugins/chai-http/) and search `Caveat` if you want to know more.

```
describe('GET Home', () => {
    it('Should return Not found', (done) => {
        chai
            .request(app)
            .get('/')
            .end(function (err, res) {
                const result = res.statusCode
                expect(result).to.equal(200)
                done()
            })
    })
})
```